# Alterar cor do ícone "X" do clear input

Tags: ionic, input, typescript

Preciso alterar cor do ícone "X" vinculada a esse input:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-input placeholder="Clear Input" clearInput></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Até o momento, pelas pesquisa achei algo referente a propriedade do input relacionado abaixo que tem cor padrão definida:

```
$text-input-md-input-clear-icon-color
```

Mas até o momento não consegui altera-lá. Alguém já passou por isso?

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou criar uma classe e usar nele? Ou ainda, usar o próprio Style no input.
Por exemplo:

```
<ion-item>
   <ion-input placeholder="Clear Input" clearInput style="color: #ff0000"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Ou ainda:

```
<style> .vermelho { color: #ff0000 } </style>
<ion-item>
   <ion-input placeholder="Clear Input" clearInput class="vermelho"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Tentei sim. Mas ocorre que altera somente a cor das palavras introduzida no input.